# How to equalise heights of two videos to be used in hstack ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to combine two videos using hstack in ffmpeg. The problem is that the two videos have different heights. And the heights can vary as the sources are dynamic. So how can I equalise the video heights to the maximum height of them and hstack them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to run the `scale2ref` filter twice.

Basic template is

```
ffmpeg -i in1 -i in2 -filter_complex
       "[0][1]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[0s][1s];
        [1s][0s]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[1s][0s];
        [0s][1s]hstack,setsar=1"   output
```

Comment: its working. thanks. but can u explain the terms please

Comment: The scale2ref filter resizes the first input with reference to the 2nd input. See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref

Comment: what is the use of oh*mdr here

Comment: It resizes the width proportionally.

Comment: @Gyan thank you! Your answer is incredible, helped me a lot.